# Add additional user requirements in spring security login and handle various exceptions

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, authorization, userdetailsservice

I am new to Spring security, I have implemented a basic user login functionality for my app using JWT. Aside from checking for username and password at login I would like to add other parameters such as a "account is verified" boolean condition but I am not sure where to add this requirement. Additionally, I need to return a 403 forbidden response status message if the "account is verified" condition is false and return a different response status message if the username password combination isn't found at all. Here Is the code I currently have which correctly handles the login of an existing user (without checking for the "account is verified" condition) and always throws a 401 when the user is found. Any feedback would be helpful.

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```java
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final ApplicationUserDetailsService applicationUserDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurityConfig(ApplicationUserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.applicationUserDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
          .cors()
          .and()
          .csrf()
          .disable()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/**")
          .permitAll()
          .anyRequest()
          .authenticated()
          .and()
          .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
          .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
          .sessionManagement()
          .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return this.bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(applicationUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
}
```

UserDetailsService

```java
public class ApplicationUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;

    public ApplicationUserDetailsService(ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository) {
        this.applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String nickname)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, UserIsNotActiveException {
        Optional<ApplicationUser> applicationUser =
                applicationUserRepository.findByNickname(nickname);
        if (!applicationUser.isPresent()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(nickname);
        }

        return new User(
                applicationUser.get().getNickname(),
                applicationUser.get().getPassword(),
                emptyList());
    }
}
```

AuthenticationFilter

```java
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            ApplicationUser applicationUser =
                    new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            applicationUser.getNickname(),
                            applicationUser.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(
            HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain,
            Authentication auth) {
        Date exp = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME);

        Key key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(KEY.getBytes());
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername());
        String token =
                Jwts.builder()
                        .setClaims(claims)
                        .signWith(key, SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
                        .setExpiration(exp)
                        .compact();
        res.addHeader("token", token);
    }
}
```

AuthorizationFilter

```java
public AuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    super(authManager);
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    String header = request.getHeader(HEADER_NAME);

    if (header == null) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = authenticate(request);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticate(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_NAME);
    if (token != null) {
        Jws<Claims> user =
                Jwts.parserBuilder()
                        .setSigningKey(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(KEY.getBytes()))
                        .build()
                        .parseClaimsJws(token);

        if (user != null) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

ApplicationUser

```java
public class ApplicationUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    String email;

    @Column(unique = true)
    String nickname;

    String biography;

    String password; // Hashed

    @Builder.Default boolean isActive = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface `UserDetails` (that is returned by the `UserDetailsService`) has some utility methods that can help you with it.

While the account is not activated, you can return `false` from the `UserDetails#isEnabled` method, or maybe you can use `UserDetails#isAccountNonLocked` as well.

Those methods will then be automatically validated on the `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider$Default(Pre/Post)AuthenticationChecks` class.

After the user goes through the activation flow, you can change the property to `true` and it will allow the user to authenticate.

Tip: add the `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your `application.properties` to help to debug.